# Retrying failed JDBC Connection

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using Spring to configure a Connection bean in Application.java as follows:

```
@Bean
public Connection getConnection(
        @Value("${sqlserver.host}") String host,
        @Value("${sqlserver.user}") String user,
        @Value("${sqlserver.password}") String password,
        @Value("${sqlserver.dbname}") String dbname){
    try {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://%s:1433;instance=MSSQLSERVER;DatabaseName=%s", host, dbname), user, password);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
```

In my controller, I am auto wiring this connection.
Also in my controller, I have scheduled methods that run at a time interval and they fetch data using this auto wired connection.
My questions are:
How can I go about closing the connection in the scheduled methods because when I close the connection, the next time the scheduled method is ran, the connection is null. And if a connection is null, how can I go about retrying to connect.

What would be the correct strategy to go about this?

Comment: Use a connection pool, that's what they were invented for.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is providing a very basic `SingleConnectionDataSource` 
[*that wraps a single Connection that is not closed after each use*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-SingleConnectionDataSource) as per the Documentation. In the same Documentation it is also mentioned that *This is primarily a test class*. To follow your method signature

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource( 
        @Value("${sqlserver.host}") String host,
        @Value("${sqlserver.user}") String user,
        @Value("${sqlserver.password}") String password,
        @Value("${sqlserver.dbname}") String dbname)) {

  SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource();
  dataSource.setSuppressClose(true);
  dataSource.setUrl(String.format("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://%s:1433;instance=MSSQLSERVER;DatabaseName=%s", host, dbname));
  dataSource.setUsername(user);
  dataSource.setPassword(password);
  return dataSource;
}
```

[There is a dedicated section in the Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-datasource) that is presenting how you could setup the `C3P0` and `DBCP` DB Connection pools that are Production-ready. Quoting directly from the above documentation:

*DBCP Configuration*:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
```

*C3P0 Configuration:*

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>
```

Comment: So does this implementation take care of closing connections? Reopening connections and retrying if connection fails

Comment: Assuming I use DriverManagerDataSource

Comment: Opening a connection to the DB is an expensive operation. DB Connection pools like DBCP, DBCP2, C3P0, Hikari, Tomcat have their own named params to keep the information of initSize (number of connections opened upon startup), maxIdle, maxSize (=active) etc. Refer to the documentation of the DB Connection pool you are planning to use to see these parameters and what are their defaults. Here's the config page for DBCP: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html